# ChangeNotifierProxyProvider builder vs update issue

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

i was using provider: ^3.0.0 in which it has ChangeNotifierProxyProvider parameters 'builder' in which i was providing a data. Now provider version is changed and now its updated version is provider: ^4.0.4 and it does not have 'builder' function now it has create and update functions. Kindly tell me, what's the logic behind the create and update.
I think crates runs only first time and updates runs every time after first time?
Am i right! But i have an issue, i have to pass some data to the next class in a parameter.
See my code

```
    ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, Shops>(
      create: (ctx)=> Shops('778b2f743f2aebd4d73d2431881a88ba54c53c01', []),
      update: (ctx, auth, prevShop)=> Shops(auth.token, prevShop.items),
      ),
```

I wanna pass the authToken to the Shop Class, in update this data can be fetched from that auth object but in create what should i do?
And i wanna pass the list of shops as a second argument in shop class, which will be the list of Shops fetched from my server, but here because i don't have and reference so i have to pass an empty list in create.

Which means when page is loaded first time there were no list of shops and when i again open same page then the shop list will be listed on the screen.

kindly help me out to clear this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this

```
ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, Shops>(
          create: (ctx) => Shops('', []),
          update: (ctx, auth, prevShop) => Shops(
              auth.token.toString(),
              prevShop == null ? [] : prevShop.items)
              ),
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

How about doing this

```
ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, Shops?>(
      create: (_) => null,
      update: (ctx, auth, prevShop) => Shops(
          auth.token.toString(),
          prevShop == null ? [] : prevShop.items)
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem. I searched the documentation and found the solution.

You need to define the function **update()** in the **Shops()** class which takes in your arguments: 
**auth.token** and **prevShop.items** in that and you need to update anything you want in that update function.

```
ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, Shops>(
      create: (ctx)=> Shops(),
      update: (ctx, auth, prevShop)=> prevShop..update(auth, prevShop.items),
      ),
```

We use **..update(auth.token, prevShop.items)** to return the same **Shops()** widget.

Comment: how can you notify that the items have been updated? If You use `notifyListeners()` inside the update function then you will get the error `setstate() or markneedsbuild() called during build`